# How to access the values of a nested object in an array, it keeps saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to access the values of a nested object in an array, I'm getting the data from an API. when I try to log the data into the console it always just shows this error, "uncaught TypeError cannot read property"

here's the code..

```
export const ItemPage = () => {

    const {id} = useParams(); 
    const url = `http://localhost:8000/details/${id}`
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("page just loaded")
         getData();
     
    },  []);
        
    const getData = async() => {
        await axios.get(url)
        .then((res)=> { 
            setData(res.data); 
            })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

        const newData = data.breeds;
  return (

    <div className='py-4 space-y-12'>
            <div className=' w-screen h-fit grid lg:flex md:flex justify-around px-12'>
                <div >
                    <img  className='w-72 h-56 rounded-2xl' src={data.url} alt="" />
                </div>
            <div className=' w-full lg:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 px-4 space-y-2 pt-6 lg:pt-0 '>
                <p className='text-xl'><strong>{newData[0].name}</strong></p>
                <p className='text-xs lg:text-sm'>{newData[0].description}</p>
                <p className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Temperament</b>: {newData[0].temperament}</p>
                <p className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Origin</b>: {newData[0].origin}</p>
                <p className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Life Span</b>: {newData[0].life_span}</p>
                <p  className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Affection level:</b>{newData[0].affection_level}</p>
                <p  className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Child Friendly:</b>{newData[0].child_friendly}</p>
                <p  className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Grooming:</b>{newData[0].grooming}</p>
                <p  className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Intelligence:</b>{newData[0].intelligence}</p>
                <p  className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Health Issue:</b>{newData[0].health_issue}</p>
                <p  className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Social Needs:</b>{newData[0].social_needs}</p>
                <p  className='text-xs lg:text-sm md:text-sm'><b>Stranger friendly:</b>{newData[0].stranger_friendly}</p>
             </div>

            </div> 
               
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render your data in the template before it's actually loaded, so accessing any property of newData throws an error;
getData is fired after template rendered but newData is accessed during render;
you are not dealing in a proper way with your async loaded data; a possible solution would be to use an internal state:

```
const [newData, setNewData] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
   getData()
   .then(data =>
      setNewData(data)
   );
}, [])
```

then in your template you can properly use `newData`

a nice guide with some examples: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-async-data-loading-lazy-loading-and-code-splitting-with-react

Other than that you need to keep into account that your state variable is initialized to an empty object (the parameter passed to `useState`) so in your template you can safely do {newData.aaa} since newData is {} and newData.aaa is undefined, but not {newData.bbb.ccc} since it will throw (newData.bbb = undefined and cannot read property ccc of undefined); for that you should define a state variable for the subObject like `const [subBBB, setSubBBB] = useState({})`

```
    useEffect(() => {
   getData()
   .then(data =>
      setNewData(data)
      setSubBBB(data.bbb)
   );
}, [])
```

now {subBBB.ccc} is safely accessible
this is obviously just a possible solution, another one would be to initialize the state to {bbb: undefined}...

Comment: I did exactly the same thing and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: you are still using constant newData in your template defined as data.breeds but data is initially undefined;
please try to delete that row and use in your template just `data`

Comment: sorry I'm not understanding you well enough,  why did you use ` .then(data => setNewData(data))` in the useEffect? am I not doing the same thing in the body of getData function??

Comment: you do but then you're not using {data.whateverYouNeed} in your template, instead you use {newData.whateverYouNeed}, having newData defined as `const newData = data.breeds` which is most likely where your code breaks: at that point the async getData() hasn't completed yet and so data is undefined, meaning it's impossible to access data.breeds

Comment: I have a nested object in an array (I don't know if I got this right), anytime I try to access the value by using `newData.breeds[0].name` it breaks the code but I can access other values that aren't nested when I just use `newData.whateverTheyAre`

Comment: no I think that the definition of `newData` breaks the code as I explained above, so you should simply delete it and access your data as {data.breeds[0].whatever....} in the template... Then this is obviously not super nice, so you can define other states for shorter access to subproperties, but that is another thing, before improvements, you should make the code to work properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243541/discussion-between-chigalakingsley-and-cereal-killer).

Comment: I've updated the answer with relevant informations :D